# IBM Rational DOORS. Filter requirements containing images.

Tags: ibm-doors

I know how to filter requirements based on their text content, but some requirements contain images. Is there a way to filter with the logical condition "contains images" or maybe "contains non-text elements"?

Answer (score 2):

Go to Tools->Filter, and select

**Attribute:** `Object Text`

**Condition:** `contains`

**Value:** `<Picture>`

and click Apply.

Note that `<Picture>` is case-sensitive.

You can also set condition to `is equal to` which seems to do the same as `contains`.

Or if you use condition `is not equal to` then you filter out objects containing pictures so you don't see them.

Comment: It didn't work on my end, and I have verified there are images in one of the columns. Any idea why this is not working?

Comment: Works for me with picture in Object Text, on DOORS 9.6.1.9

Comment: Be specific about what sort of image - is it a picture (which is what you asked about, I'd assume this is jpeg/bmp/png which is what I tried) or an OLE (from which application?), what are the attribute details where it is inserted?

Comment: I right clicked the picture, clicked "Properties", then the "Attributes" tab. In there, I looked for the "Object Text" attribute. Its description says "System Attribute", and the Value field is empty. When picking that "Object Text" and clicking "view/edit" it shows the picture in the "Value" field. Besides, in there, it says the "Type" is "Text".

Comment: Step back - are you manually inserting the picture? Does it start as a picture file, or are you copy/pasting an OLE object? Does the picture appear in the Object Text column - or another column/attribute?

Comment: I am not inserting anything. Just checking an existing entry. Each entry has 5 columns. The image/picture is in the column of type "main". Let me know if you need more information, and thank you for your interest thus far.

Comment: OK so you aren't inserting these pictures - but do you know how they are inserted, is it by manual copy/paste or paste special, or are they are inserted by a dxl script? I was trying with only a picture, are your pictures surrounded by text? May not be a way to filter using the OOTB filtering, might have to either use DXL filtering, or create a layout DXL column and filter on that.

Comment: It is a single picture, without any text surrounding it. I am unaware of how it was inserted. I'm sorry if I wasted your time.

Comment: No prob. And what version of DOORS?

Comment: DOORS client version is *9.5.1.7*.